# Error when using YEAR, MONTH, DAY mysql functions in LiipFunctionalTest bundle

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, symfony, doctrine-orm, liipfunctionaltestbundle

I'm using `DAY`, `MONTH`, `YEAR` mysql's functions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) with `LiipFunctionalTestBundle`. When I run the test I'm getting:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: YEAR`

At the end, the test failed. I guess it's because of that.

This is my `config_test` file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.filesystem
        name: MOCKSESSID

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true

liip_functional_test: 
  cache_sqlite_db: true
  authentication:
    username: "root"
    password: "admin"

doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        driver:   pdo_sqlite
        path:     %kernel.cache_dir%/test.db
  orm:
    dql: 
      datetime_functions:
        YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
        MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
        DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
```

In my code I use them as:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$emConfig = $em->getConfiguration();
$emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
$emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('MONTH', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month');
$emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DAY', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day');

....
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$dql = $em->createQuery('SELECT um FROM Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Menu um WHERE 
                  um.user = :id and 
                  YEAR(um.day) = :year and 
                  MONTH(um.day) = :month and 
                  DAY(um.day) = :day');
      $dql->setParameter('id', $id);
      $dql->setParameter('year', $now->format("Y"));
      $dql->setParameter('month', $now->format("m"));
      $dql->setParameter('day', $now->format("d"));
```

If I run the application I don't have problems.

Comment: A typo in the yml definitions? `DoctrinceExtensions ` instead of  `DoctrineExtensions `?

Comment: Sure. But still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not related to `mysql` but to `sqlite`. I run my tests using `sqlite` which throws the exception above. The simplest way I found to solve the issue is change the queries with a general version that both databases could understand.

I also thought to have two versions of every query, one for `mysql` and one for `sqlite`, and play with the environment when the application execute the tests. For example, if I'm using the `test` environment use the `sqlite` query, otherwise use `mysql`. However I consider this option very dependent and hard to maintain in the future.